# Dynamically subscribe/unsubscribe in TPL Dataflow

Tags: c#, concurrency, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I have a stream of messages and based on some criteria I want each consumer to be able to process some of them in parallel. Each consumer should be able to subscribe and unsubscribe dynamically.
[image]

I have the following input data constraints:

- Around 500 messages per seconds
- Around 15000 consumers
- Around 500 categories
- In most cases, each consumer is subscribed for 1-3 categories.

So far this is what I have:

```
public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var consumer1 = new Consumer("Consumer1");
        consumer1.SubscribeForCategory(1);
        consumer1.SubscribeForCategory(2);

        var consumer2 = new Consumer("Consumer2");
        consumer2.SubscribeForCategory(2);
        consumer2.SubscribeForCategory(3);
        consumer2.SubscribeForCategory(4);

        var consumer3 = new Consumer("Consumer3");
        consumer3.SubscribeForCategory(3);
        consumer3.SubscribeForCategory(4);

        var consumers = new[] {consumer1, consumer2, consumer3};
        var publisher = new Publisher(consumers);

        var message1 = new Message(1, "message1 test");
        var message2 = new Message(2, "message2");
        var message3 = new Message(1, "message3");
        var message4 = new Message(3, "message4 test");
        var message5 = new Message(4, "message5");
        var message6 = new Message(3, "message6");

        var messages = new[] {message1, message2, message3, message4, message5, message6};

        foreach (var message in messages)
        {
            publisher.Publish(message);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Message
{
    public Message(int categoryId, string data)
    {
        CategoryId = categoryId;
        Data = data;
    }

    public int CategoryId { get; }

    public string Data { get; }
}

public class Publisher
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<Consumer> _consumers;

    public Publisher(IEnumerable<Consumer> consumers)
    {
        _consumers = consumers;
    }

    public void Publish(Message message)
    {
        IEnumerable<Consumer> consumers = _consumers.Where(c => c.CategoryIds.Contains(message.CategoryId));
        foreach (Consumer consumer in consumers)
        {
            consumer.AddMessage(message);
        }
    }
}

public class Consumer
{
    private readonly HashSet<int> _categoryIds;
    private readonly ActionBlock<Message> _queue;

    public Consumer(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        _categoryIds = new HashSet<int>();

        _queue = new ActionBlock<Message>(async m => { await Foo(m); }, 
                                          new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions 
                                          {
                                              MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1, 
                                              SingleProducerConstrained = true
                                          });
    }

    public string Name { get; }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<int> CategoryIds => _categoryIds;

    public void AddMessage(Message message)
    {
        bool accepted = _queue.Post(message);
        if (!accepted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message has been rejected!");
        }
    }

    public void SubscribeForCategory(int categoryId)
    {
        _categoryIds.Add(categoryId);
    }

    private async Task Foo(Message message)
    {
        // process message
        await Task.Delay(10);

        if (message.Data.Contains("test"))
        {
            _categoryIds.Remove(message.CategoryId);
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"[{Name}] - category id: [{message.CategoryId}] data: [{message.Data}]");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, there are several issues with that solution:

1. While consumer process each message there is the possibility to unsubscribe for some message which has been added to the **ActionBlock** input queue.
2. In Publisher.cs I am iterating over each account category collection and later in Account Foo method, there is a chance to remove some category which will lead to the following exception: **System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.**
3. Also I am not pretty sure whether is a good idea to have "dispatching logic" into publisher.Publish()

One possible solution is to forward all messages to each consumer (and each consumer should take a decision whether should or shouldn't process it) but I am afraid that this is going to be much slower.

I am aware of actor model-based frameworks like Akka.Net and Microsoft Orleans, but I want all of this to happen in-process (if it's achievable of course).

Does anyone have a more elegant solution? Do you have any suggestions on how can I improve the current approach?

Comment: How many are the categories? Also each consumer subscribes to how many categories concurrently on average?

Comment: I have around 500 categories. It depends. In most cases around 1-3 categories in rare cases for more than 150.

Comment: Have you tried using a [synchronization primitive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/overview-of-synchronization-primitives) to allow you to access collections without running into `System.InvalidOperationException`

Comment: @DekuDesu I haven't. But  IMO adding any kind of exclusive lock will add additional performance impact.

Comment: Unfortunately thread safety will always come at a performance impact. It should be noted however, that reliability and security in the mutability of your data often matters more than a few percentage points of performance.

Comment: @chunk1ty Dataflow already offers the functionality you want, you don't need to write all that code.  All you need is to link blocks together and specify a predicate in the link to filter items. You can break a link at runtime. The `Publisher` should be a `TransformBlock` itself. An `ActionBlock` isn't a queue, it's the actual Consumer

Comment: @chunk1ty btw TPL Dataflow grew out of Microsoft Robotics, so it was built from the start to provide blocks that communicate with each other in large meshes.

Comment: BTW how come you have 15K consumers? What do they do? Are they really different methods or are they the same method with different reference/config data? Why not pass that data to the consumer along with each message? Or do they represent different remote devices or services?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Same class different objects. They do some kind of calculations (message object in my case is a little more complicated), from time to time they may do a write DB operations (based on business rules). 
In most cases (80-90%), each consumer is interested only in 1-2 messages.

Comment: @chunk1ty database operations should go to different blocks. And since each "consumer" only receives two messages, there shouldn't be so many block instances. I have a pipeline where the first block requests air ticket reports from airlines, the 2nd block parses it and extracts ticket numbers, 3rd block retrieves ticket records from HTTP services using those tickets, a batch block to combine eg 100 records per batch and a final block that writes each batch to the database using SqlBulkCopy

Comment: @chunk1ty a dataflow pipeline is little different from a *command-line* pipeline of CLI tools combined in a chain, with each one's output feeding the next. Instead of one fat tool doing many things, you have many tools doing one thing each. The complex behavior is produced by chaining all these together

Comment: @chunk1ty CSP/DataFlow is *very* different from Agents and Akka. I know people have tried to build "agents', especially mailbox-like agents with Dataflow but these are far heavier than Akka agents. Instead of using 15K agents that represent a single device/consumer and await 2 messages before writing some state to the database, you'd have 1 TransformBlock that eg modifies the state of an object stored in a ConcurrentDictionary and emit any results downstream to an ActionBlock that saves them in a database. The specifics matter

Comment: @chunk1ty if you want Akka-like agents why not use Akka.NET? Akka works in-process. Agents and Dataflow are very different models and what you describe is an agent architecture. To use a Dataflow you'd need to somehow convert the business process into a series of steps/blocks, or perhaps a state machine. Instead of N consumers you'd have N items. Each time an event came that would case a state change, that item would be sent to the appropriate block for processing, and await a message to move it downstream. Doable, especially for relatively stable state machines

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am planning to use MS Orleans. As far as I understood there are many infrastructure configurations (k8s configurations), which will involve people from other departments in my situation. Because of that as a first step, I would like to achieve efficient parallel execution, refactor some components, and decoupling some business rules. The second step should solve our scalability issues with some Actor-based model (most likely MS Orleans).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TPL DataFlow library already provides what you want. Its blocks aren't queues, they're the actual producers and consumers. You could remove almost *all* of the code you added. You could even use a LINQ query to create and link the "publisher" and "consumers" :

```
var n=10;
var consumers=( from i in Enumerable.Range(0,n)
                let categories=new ConcurrentDictinoary<int,int>()
                select new { 
                             Block=new ActionBlock(msg=>Consume(msg,categories)
                                                        ,blockOptions),
                             Categories=categories
                }).ToArray();

foreach(var pair in consumers)
{
    publisher.LinkTo(pair.Block,linkOption,msg=>IsAllowed(msg,pair.Category));
}

bool IsAllowed(Message msg,ConcurrentDictionary<int,int> categories)
{
    return categories.ContainsKey(msg.CategoryId);
}

async Task Consume(Message message,ConcurrentDictinary<int,int> categories)
{
    if (message.Data.Contains("test"))
    {
        categories.TryRemove(message.CategoryId);
    }
    ...
}
```

It's no accident that the blocks work with functions. The Dataflow library and the CSP paradigm it's based on are very different from OOP, and much closer to functional programming.

By the way, TPL Dataflow grew out of the Microsoft Robotics Frameworks and the [Concurrency Runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_and_Coordination_Runtime). In robotics and automation there are a *lot* of microprocessors exchanging messages. Dataflow It's specifically built to create complex processing meshes and handle lots of message.

**Explanation**

Dataflow isn't a set of queues, it contains active blocks that are meant to be linked in a pipeline. An ActionBlock isn't a queue, it *has* a queue. In reality it's a Consumer, typically found at the tail of a pipeline. A TransformBlock receives incoming messages, processes them one by one then sends them to any linked blocks.

Blocks are linked, so you don't need to manually take messages from one block and pass them to another. The Link can contain a predicate, used to filter the messages accepted by target blocks. It's possible to cut a link by calling `Dispose` on it.

Assuming this is the "consumer" method :

```
async Task Consume(Message message)
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine($"Category id: [{message.CategoryId}] data: [{message.Data}]");
}
```

You can create a few ActionBlocks, perhaps in an array :

```
var consumers=new[]{
     new ActionBlock(Consume),
     new ActionBlock(Consume),
     new ActionBlock(Consume)
};
```

Each action block could use a different delegate of course.

The "head" of the pipeline should probably be a TransformBlock. In this case, the Publisher doesn't do anything except get linked to the target blocks. At least we can print something:

```
Message PassThrough(Message message)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Incoming");
    return Message;
}

var publisher=new TransformBlock(PassThrough);
```

You can link the "publisher" to the "consumers" with `LinkTo` :

```
var options=new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion=true};

var link1=publisher.LinkTo(consumers[0],options, msg=>msg.CategoryId % 3==0);
var link2=publisher.LinkTo(consumers[1],options, msg=>msg.CategoryId % 3==1);
var link3=publisher.LinkTo(consumers[2],options, msg=>msg.CategoryId % 3==2);
```

Messages produced by the "publisher" block will be sent to the first target whose link predicate accepts it. Messages are offered to links in the order they were created. If no link accepts the message, it will stay in the output queue and block it.

In real scenarios one should always ensure that all messages are handle or that there is a block that can handle anything that doesn't match.

```
public.LinkTo(theOtherBlock,options);
```

The `link1`, `link2`, `link3` objects are just `IDisposeable`s. They can be used to break a link :

```
link2.Dispose();
```

Links can be created and broken at any time, changing the shape of the pipeline (or mesh in more complex designs) as needed. Any messages already posted to a target block's queue won't be discarded if a link is broken or modified though.

To reduce the number of unwanted messages we can add a bound to each block's input queue:

```
var blockOptions=new DataflowBlockOptions { BoundedCapacity=1 };

var consumers=new[]{
     new ActionBlock(Consume,blockOptions),
     new ActionBlock(Consume,blockOptions),
     new ActionBlock(Consume,blockOptions)
};
```

To change the accepted messages dynamically, we can store the values in eg a `ConcurrentDictionary`. A predicate may be trying to check a message at the same time a consumer modifies the permitted values:

```
ConcurrentDictionary[] _allowedCategories=new[] {
    new ConcurrentDictionary<int,int>(),
    new ConcurrentDictionary<int,int>(),
    new ConcurrentDictionary<int,int>(),
};

async Task Consume(Message message,ConcurrentDictinary<int,int> categories)
{
    if (message.Data.Contains("test"))
    {
        categories.TryRemove(message.CategoryId);
    }
    ...
}
```

And the "consumers" change to

```
var consumers=new[]{
     new ActionBlock(msg=>Consume(msg,categories[0])),
     new ActionBlock(msg=>Consume(msg,categories[1])),
     new ActionBlock(msg=>Consume(msg,categories[2]))
};
```

It's better to create a separate method for the link predicate:

```
bool IsAllowed(Message msg,ConcurrentDictionary<int,int> categories)
{
    return categories.ContainsKey(msg.CategoryId);
}

var link1=publisher.LinkTo(consumers[0],options, msg=>IsAllowed(msg,categories[0]));
var link2=publisher.LinkTo(consumers[1],options, msg=>IsAllowed(msg,categories[1]));
```

One could create all these with LINQ and `Enumerable.Range. Whether that's a good idea is another matter :

```
var n=10;
var consumers=( from i in Enumerable.Range(0,n)
                         let categories=new ConcurrentDictinoary<int,int>()
                         select new { 
                             Block=new ActionBlock(msg=>Consume(msg,categories)
                                                        ,blockOptions),
                             Categories=categories
                         }).ToArray();

foreach(var pair in consumers)
{
    publisher.LinkTo(pair.Block,linkOption,msg=>IsAllowed(msg,pair.Category));
}
```

No matter how the mesh is built, publishing to it is the same. Use `SendAsync` on the head block

```
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
{
    var msg=new Message(...);
    await publisher.SendAsync(msg);
}
```

Comment: It looks promising and more elegant. I read about TransformBlock but I wasn't sure how can I change filter criteria at runtime. When I have time I have to check it for sure.

Comment: I noticed that you aren't using SingleProducerConstrained option in ActionBlock. What is the reason?

Comment: @chunk1ty no reason other than writing a really long answer from scratch

Comment: The OP has 15,000 consumers, and each consumer is/has a dataflow block. Linking the producer block with 15,000 consumer blocks with the [`LinkTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.linkto)+predicate, means that the predicate (the `IsAllowed` method) will be invoked 15,000 times for each message. Times 500 messages per second it sums to 7,500,000 invocations per second.  That's the kind of overhead that I assumed it's unacceptable, and this is why I didn't propose this solution in my answer.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias unless there's no reason to use 15K consumers that will receive only 2 messages each. The OP is trying to use ActionBlock as an Akka agent. That's a *very* different paradigm. A Dataflow is similar to a shell script pipeline. You don't create 15K instances of a program to handle 15K rows from a file. You create a pipeline that splits the lines and passes them processes them one by one

Answer (score 1):

I think that the entity `Category` is missing from your model, and adding it will improve your model not only conceptually but also performance-wise. Each category can hold a list of the consumers that are subscribed for this category, making it trivial to send a message only to the subscribed consumers.

For solving the issue of the thread-safety my suggestion is to use [immutable collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable) instead of mutable `HashSet<T>`s or `List<T>`s. The immutable collections offer the advantage that they can be updated safely and atomically with low-lock techniques ([`ImmutableInterlocked.Update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutableinterlocked.update) method), and can provide at any time a snapshot of their contents that is unaffected by future modifications. If you are asking how it is possible to mutate an immutable collection, the answer is that you are not mutating it, instead you are replacing the reference with a different immutable collection. These structures are implemented in a way that allows high reusability of their internal bits and pieces. For example adding an item in a [`ImmutableHashSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablehashset-1) that already holds 1,000,000 items, does not require the allocation of a new memory block that contains all the old items plus the new one. Only a handful of tiny objects (nodes in the internal binary tree) will be allocated.

This convenience comes at a price: most operations on immutable collections are at least 10 times slower than the same operations on their mutable counterparts. Most probably this overhead will be negligible in the grand scheme of things, but you may want to profile and measure it yourself, and judge whether it is impactful or not.

The `Category` class:

```
public class Category
{
    private ImmutableHashSet<Consumer> _consumers;

    public int Id { get; }
    public ImmutableHashSet<Consumer> Consumers => Volatile.Read(ref _consumers);

    public Category(int id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        _consumers = ImmutableHashSet.Create<Consumer>();
    }

    public void SubscribeConsumer(Consumer consumer) =>
        ImmutableInterlocked.Update(ref _consumers, col => col.Add(consumer));

    public void UnsubscribeConsumer(Consumer consumer) =>
        ImmutableInterlocked.Update(ref _consumers, col => col.Remove(consumer));
}
```

Notice the [`Volatile.Read`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.volatile.read), that ensures that the most recent reference stored in the `_consumers` field will be immediately visible to all threads accessing the `Consumers` property.

The `Consumer` class:

```
public class Consumer
{
    private readonly ActionBlock<Message> _block;
    private IImmutableList<Category> _categories;

    public string Name { get; }
    public IImmutableList<Category> Categories => Volatile.Read(ref _categories);

    public Consumer(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        _categories = ImmutableArray.Create<Category>();
        _block = new ActionBlock<Message>(async message =>
        {
            if (!Categories.Any(cat => cat.Id == message.CategoryId)) return;
            // Process message...
        });
    }

    public void SendMessage(Message message)
    {
        bool accepted = _block.Post(message);
        Debug.Assert(accepted);
    }

    public void SubscribeForCategory(Category category)
    {
        ImmutableInterlocked.Update(ref _categories, col => col.Add(category));
        category.SubscribeConsumer(this);
    }

    public void UnsubscribeForCategory(Category category)
    {
        ImmutableInterlocked.Update(ref _categories, col => col.Remove(category));
        category.UnsubscribeConsumer(this);
    }
}
```

Notice that the `SubscribeForCategory` method has also the responsibility of adding the reverse relation (category `->` consumer). In the above implementation these two relations are not added atomically in regard with each other, meaning that an observer could see a consumer subscribed to a category, and the category not subscribed to the consumer. From your description is seems that no such observer exists in your app, so this inconsistency probably doesn't matter too much.

The `Publisher` class needs to hold a list of categories, instead of consumers:

```
public class Publisher
{
    private readonly Dictionary<int, Category> _categories;

    public Publisher(IEnumerable<Category> categories)
    {
        _categories = categories.ToDictionary(cat => cat.Id);
    }

    public void Publish(Message message)
    {
        var category = _categories[message.CategoryId];
        foreach (Consumer consumer in category.Consumers)
            consumer.SendMessage(message);
    }
}
```

Notice how simpler the `Publish` method is.